# Should I use only one drawable vector icon for all screen sizes?

Tags: android

Here I am talking about the performance, is it better to use different sizes of the same vector icon for different screen sizes?
What I understand is, if I use different vector icon sizes then the app doesn't need to scale up or scale down the vector icon and this helps a tiny bit of performance for the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating other sizes of it will not affect performance. The runtime must interpret the vector instructions exactly the same way regardless of size.

But theoretically, a set of raster images (created at all the different sizes) could perform better than the equivalent vector image if the image is sufficiently complicated to express in vector form. This is because loading a raster image that doesn't require resizing merely means reading all the pixels from the image. But raster images usually take more space than vector, and especially so since you need multiple sizes of them.

Comment: So if I use vector icons ( those come preinstalled in android studio), by default the size is 24*24, this means it resizes itself according to the screen? In my question I meant different sizes of vector images not raster images. I don't use complicated vector icon, I just use the default ones in android studio. So, if select a vector asset by default 24*24 then I don't need other sizes for other densities?

Comment: Yes, I understand you’re asking about vector but your comment about performance can only be answered in comparison to the alternative, which is raster images. There is no reason whatsoever to create multiple sizes of a vector artwork, if that’s what you mean. Raster is theoretically better for performance than vector, but only if you include all the sizes it might be displayed at. And the performance advantage would be negligible unless you have an image that is complicated for vector art.

Comment: One more related question,  now should I create one vector drawable icon for all screen sizes or create 4 raster image?

Comment: If your icon looks like a photo or 3D CG, that lends itself better to raster. If it is flat shapes, that tends to lend itself better to vector.